# State preservation of HTML hosted inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, state, cross-origin-read-blocking

How can I save state of a site hosted inside an iframe when the user navigates through multiple sites inside html hosted inside the iframe when there is an issue of cross origin and we can't access contentDocument of Iframe.

New to javascript, any leads would be helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean, save the state?  What state?  It's cross-origin, so you can't do anything really.

Comment: Save the state means I want to save the last link visited by the user and scroll position of the last visited page.

Comment: You won't be able to do that cross-origin.